# How to assign an event to a drawable button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to assign an event to a button, the button is declared as a Bitmap, I cannot seem to figure out how to add a listener to it, or even simply an event that I can call when the button is touched.

```
moregamesbtn = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.moregames);

Bitmap moregamesbtn;
```

Edit - I attempted this, with no success;

```
moregamesbtn = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.moregames);


        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.drawable.moregames);
        imgButton.setImageBitmap(moregamesbtn);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
             @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.e("MyApplication", "Pressing more games button");
                 }
                });
```

Comment: Bitmap is not a button its a Bitmap image, you need to set the image to a button or imageview

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign your Bitmap to the Button background

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(bdrawable);
```

Then make a onButtonClick Listener.

EDIT:
you might want to check this out as well:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry to be very much a newbie on this, whereabouts would I be placing this piece of code?

Comment: Hi, the only issue is my project does not have any xml files in layout, in fact, layout folder is empty, I am using a .java files only

Comment: You should add an xml file then. They are very useful if not almost necessary for the UI in your app.